# How to get the path of a folder that's compiled into a python exe?

Tags: python, directory, path, executable

I have made a script and compiled it into an exe using pyinstaller. Along with the script I included a folder and my script needs to know the path of that folder. How would I find the folder's path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
#HERE IT FINDS THE PATH

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
    try:
        app_full_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
        application_path = os.path.dirname(app_full_path)
    except NameError:
        application_path = os.getcwd()

path = os.path.join(application_path)
```

and next add on this variable your name of your .exe file:

```
final_path = (path + '\\yourpath.exe')
```

Comment: Thanks!! (Τυχαίνει να είμαι και εγώ Έλληνας. Ευχαριστώ πολύ φίλε)

Comment: Your welcome! (Να'σαι καλά φίλε! Κυριολεκτικά έψαχνα και εγώ το ίδιο, και βρήκα την λύση λίγα λεπτά πρίν το ποστάρεις .)

Comment: @Jimminer Please talk on English whenever possible.